# Problems with automatic image carousel when data is dynamic from an api using react native

Tags: react-native, axios, react-hooks, carousel

I am implementing an image carousel which has an automatic rotation. When I implement it with static data (for example: creating a constant with an array) it works just the way I want it to.

However when I am getting the data from an api using axios, the carrosuel has a wrong behavior. The wrong behavior is as follows:

Swipe to the second image on the carousel and before moving on to the third image, go back to the first image and then go to the third image, then go to the fourth image, go back to the first image, and then go to the first image. fourth, this behavior is repeated x times.

So I think the problem is when I use axios. I attach the code of the classes that intervene in the problem that I am currently presenting.

I am using react native 0.62 with hooks and axios

HomeScreen.js

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import CategoriesScreen from "./Categories/CategoriesScreen";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import Carousel from "./Banner/BannerOficial";
import { axiosClient } from "../../config/axios";

export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {


  const [banners, setBanners] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getBannersAPI();
  }, []);

  function getBannersAPI(){
    axiosClient
    .get("/service/banner_available")
    .then(async function (response) {
      setBanners(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error cargando los banners: ", error);
    });
  }
  
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <ScrollView>
        <Carousel data={banners} />
        <CategoriesScreen navigation={navigation} />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Carousel.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions, FlatList, Animated } from 'react-native'
import CarouselItem from './BannerItem'


const { width, heigth } = Dimensions.get('window')
let flatList

function infiniteScroll(dataList){
    const numberOfData = dataList.length
    let scrollValue = 0, scrolled = 0

    setInterval(function() {
        scrolled ++
        if(scrolled < numberOfData)
        scrollValue = scrollValue + width

        else{
            scrollValue = 0
            scrolled = 0
        }

        this.flatList.scrollToOffset({ animated: true, offset: scrollValue})
        
    }, 3000)
}


const Carousel = ({ data }) => {
    const scrollX = new Animated.Value(0)
    let position = Animated.divide(scrollX, width)
    const [dataList, setDataList] = useState(data)

    useEffect(()=> {
        setDataList(data)
        infiniteScroll(dataList)
    })


    if (data && data.length) {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList data={data}
                ref = {(flatList) => {this.flatList = flatList}}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'key' + index}
                    horizontal
                    pagingEnabled
                    scrollEnabled
                    snapToAlignment="center"
                    scrollEventThrottle={16}
                    decelerationRate={"fast"}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => {
                        return <CarouselItem item={item} />
                    }}
                    onScroll={Animated.event(
                        [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }]
                    )}
                />

                <View style={styles.dotView}>
                    {data.map((_, i) => {
                        let opacity = position.interpolate({
                            inputRange: [i - 1, i, i + 1],
                            outputRange: [0.3, 1, 0.3],
                            extrapolate: 'clamp'
                        })
                        return (
                            <Animated.View
                                key={i}
                                style={{ opacity, height: 10, width: 10, backgroundColor: '#595959', margin: 8, borderRadius: 5 }}
                            />
                        )
                    })}

                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }

    console.log('Please provide Images')
    return null
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    dotView: { flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'}
})

export default Carousel
```

CarouselItem.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Image, Dimensions} from 'react-native';

const { width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')

const CarouselItem = ({item}) => {
    return(
        <View style={styles.cardView}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source = {{ uri: item.imagePath}}/>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    cardView:{
        flex:1,
        width: width -20,
        height: height / 7,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        margin: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {width: 0.5, height: 0.5},
        shadowOpacity: 0.5, 
        shadowRadius: 3,
        elevation: 5,
    },
    image: {
        width: width-20,
        height: height / 3,
        borderRadius: 10
    }
})

export default CarouselItem
```